# Set timer on procedure?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i'm building an application with a Twebbrowser component that needs to navigate to only 1 Page, the application will be in the Windows autostart so it's possible that there isn't any internet connectivity on the first navigate, so i want to check for the title of the page, if it's not the right one, navigate again. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.titlechange(Sender: TObject; const Text: WideString);
begin
if Text = 'Untitled Document' then
begin
StaticText1.Visible := False;
Timer4.Enabled := False;
end
else
webbrowser1.Navigate('http://website.com');
end;
```

I want to have a 5 second timer on that procedure, and if the navigation was successful and the title is "Untitled Document" the timer should be disabled.

How can i do that ?

Thanks!

---

i am back to my original request, i implemented the proposed solution, this does only work sometimes, if there's no network connected sometimes there's a "Navigation to the Webpage was canceled" this triggers OnDocumentComplete i am thinking that the LocationName function in Twebbrowser itself has a wrong functionality description.

My original code however does work, i just need a timer on it ! Can someone help me with that please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `OnNavigatError` and `OnDocumentComplete` events instead, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer4Timer(nil);
end; 

procedure TForm1.Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer4.Enabled := False;
  webbrowser1.Navigate('http://website.com');
end;

procedure TForm1.webbrowser1NavigateError(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant; var Frame: OleVariant; var StatusCode: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  Timer4.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.webbrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
  if webbrowser1.LocationName = 'Untitled Document' then
  begin
    StaticText1.Visible := False;
  end
  else begin
    Timer4.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i'm a bit of a Delphi newbie, i replaced my Timer4 with your code and inserted the Timer4Timer(nil); in my FormCreate procedure, i'm getting undeclared identifier errors on the webbrowser1NavigateError, webbrowser1DocumentComplete, and webbrowser1.LocationName, what do i have to do ?

Comment: @user990767 you will have to click on the browser component, then on the events tab of the object browser, and then double click on the "DocumentComplete" event, and copy in the contents of the webbrowser1DocumentComplete procedure. And repeat for the others. The name of the procedures here is the object name and event combined.